# Windows 10 SSH folder and known_hosts file is missing

Tags: ssh, openssh

> On windows it is usually stored in the %USERPROFILE%\ssh or
> %USERPROFILE%.ssh folders.

However I do not see the ssh folders when going to %USERPROFILE%.
Is it possible to create the ssh folder and the known_hosts file myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is expected.

You can in a CMD do:

```
cd "%USERPROFILE%"
mkdir .ssh
```

From there, assuming you have ssh-keygen in your PATH (which is included in [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) for example), you can type:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ""
```

That will generate a key in the default path `~/.ssh(/id_rsa[.pub])`, with `~/.ssh` being translated in `%USERPROFILE%\.ssh`